# Creating a dynamic function for creating checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a dynamic function that I can pass a range to and it will generate the checkbox in the cells in that range. I have it generating checkboxes but I can't figure out how to change it to use a dynamic range that is passed as a parameter when I call the sub.

How would I change my sub to be able to do this? Here is my code so far...

```
Public Sub chkPopulateFields(R As Range)
    Dim chk As Variant
    Dim t As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Me.Worksheets(1)
        .CheckBoxes.Delete
        For i = 4 To 10
            Set t = .Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3))
            Set chk = .CheckBoxes.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
        Next
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a dynamic function that I can pass a range to and it will generate the checkbox in the cells in that range.

You can use `For Each` to loop through each cell in a range. Also I added one more paramenter `ws As Worksheet` so that you can target the relevant worksheet.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    chkPopulateFields Range("A1:C4"), Sheet1
End Sub

Public Sub chkPopulateFields(R As Range, ws As Worksheet)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim chk As Object

    With ws
        .CheckBoxes.Delete
        For Each rng In R
            Set chk = .CheckBoxes.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You could have used the `Worksheet` property of the `range` object (i.e. `R.Worksheet`)

Comment: True. I could have. But then you would have to fully qualify `Range("A1:C4")` else it will refer to the activesheet. But honestly `R.Worksheet` did not even cross my mind :)

Comment: It's very convenient as it would have allowed for something like: `With rng`   ` Set chk = .Worksheet.CheckBoxes.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)`   `End With`. Anyhow, your answer is very efficient, as always.

Comment: Yes it would have been. but unfortunately it also can cause lot of confusion. If you want to use `R.Worksheet` then fully qualify the range. For example, `chkPopulateFields Sheet1.Range("A1:C4")` In this case we can get rid of `ws As Worksheet` and then replace `With ws` with `With R.Worksheet` :)

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that *the 1With ws` would be replaced by `With R`* (excluding the `.Worksheet`)